# Would this question be well received here?

Tags: discussion

I've asked an [orbital mechanics math question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20590/12102) in Space Exploration Stackexchange first because there are a few math heavy-hitters there who can explain well. But if nobody bites, I am thinking of moving the question here.

However, sometimes when I ask a question in a site where I have a low score it is not well received because I have not properly gauged what is expected of a new user question in terms of background or independent research.

If I'm not able to get an answer there, is my question likely to survive here?

Comment: +1 for asking here first.

Comment: Depends how you define "well received." It won't be closed, but it's awfully long and has lots of code. I couldn't bring myself to read every word. You might get an answer from someone more patient than I, but it would also help to at least include a tl;dr (I've actually never seen such a thing on this site because, well, it's math, and if there's something you can leave out you probably should leave it out, but the equivalent is to include a more concise version in the same post).

Comment: @MattSamuel I see what you mean - no need to explain to a room full of mathematicians *why* I'd like to understand some math.

Comment: @uhoh You might want to include a brief explanation of the motivation to appease the trigger happy homework closers.

Comment: @MattSamuel Do you think one can confuse this question with a homework plz-give-meh-the-full-solution-asap question?

Comment: @Did Certainly not as is, but with all of the non-mathematical details cut out who knows.

Comment: @MattSamuel Then why invoke the fictitious category of "trigger happy homework closers"?

Comment: @Did stuff happens. It's possible I might end up with a version that could look like something a question-closer might find appetizing, I've asked a question which is pretty much asking for advice, so I'll get out my collection of grains of salt and have the ready. In the last year I've had the experience of being "new" in several SE sites, and "what are the the close-triggers here for questions like mine?" is always the first thing I need to figure out.

Comment: In principle you might ask this at [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions), where many questions involve interplay between mathematics and software of various kinds.  However there are no "orbital mechanics" questions there yet, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @hardmath I've been hoping to think of a good "first question" there for a while, thanks for reminding me, I'll take a closer look again.

Comment: If you post the question here and it gets well received but has low attention, I don't mind lending you some bounty rep.

Comment: @uhoh Sorry but what is a "question-closer"?

Comment: @Did I'm voting to close your comment on the grounds that it may attract further comments that could be considered primarily opinion-based. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't understand your upvote: if all those users unsure about how their questions would be received asked about it here, Meta.Math.SE would become a nightmare. The OP should simply ask the question and see what happens, no big deal. If the question gets closed, it will get so with a explanatory message and some comments allowing for the OP to correct and reopen it.

Comment: @AlexM. I believe that if that started happening, we'd just close those questions and link them to this question and similar.

Comment: uhoh  Your question at its current home would hardly be interpreted as a stark problem-statement-question, lacking anything resembling research/ or effort, or context. I doubt any of us are hungry to/have an appetite for closing such questions. And I personally think the question is NOT off-topic for any reason, too....

Comment: ...However, you might also want to consider this...Part of being well-received at any site requires a willingness to suspend pre-conceived suspicions that some people on the site are waiting and  lurking in the shadows, hoping to feed off of any asker, and cast  spells on your question, dooming them to closure and/or deletion.

Comment: @amWhy my only firm preconceptions are that humans are present, and they always come in an amazingly wide variety of configurations and fill factors.

Comment: @hardmath have [asked this](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26537/17869) there for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that the question here might not get that attention not only because of the reputation but also due to the field you are trying to apply the mathematics on. I suggest you first try explore the tags and questions on the site to see if some similar questions have been posted  and how well they were received.  If you are really in need for an answer why not try to post it and see what happens after that? I agree with you that reputation might be an important factor but out of experience if your question is  well-constructed (which is the case here) It will not be at least downvoted.

Comment: I know reputation matters for answers. I used to have to work hard for reputation but now I get an upvote for any garbage I post. Didn't think it mattered too much for questions.

Comment: Explore the tags and questions here is of course excellent advice. While it is just common sense, it is easy to forget to do when *asking a question* or *solving a problem* is on one's mind, so your reminder is well taken.

Comment: @MattSamuel "but now I get an upvote for any garbage I post" +1

Comment: @silvascientist It's a massive exaggeration,, but it does seem a bit easier.

Comment: @MattSamuel It was just a joke. Giving you an upvote even for mentioning that you get an upvote for any garbage you post.

Comment: @silvascientist Ah, I get it. Jokes are easy to miss in text!

Answer (score 1):

The [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20590/12102) in question has now received several answers, somewhat lubricated by bounties. If I need to go deeper I'll ask here. Thanks to everyone for your helpful comments and for the answer!